# uniformly bounded proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $f_n:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Prove that if $f_n$ converges to f uniformly on E, then {$f_n$} is uniformly bounded on $E$, and $f$ is a bounded function on $E$.

I honestly just need help on how to start this problem.

We can assume that $f_n:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $f_n$ converges to f uniformly on $E$. So by definition we have that $|f_n-f| < \varepsilon$.

We also have that $|f_n| \leq M_n$ as $f_n$ is bounded.

Here is what I have so far:

Take $|f|=|f-f_n+f_n|\leq|f_n-f|+|f_n| < \varepsilon + M_n$, which is true for all $n \geq N$.

I'm unsure where to go with this, or if this is even right.

I don't want the answer, I just need some guidance.

Comment: Please use latex for the math formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that $f$ is a bounded function on $E$, say by $M=\varepsilon + M_N$. In your notation, if $n\ge N$, then $\sup_{x\in E}|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le \varepsilon$. In other words, the graphs of the functions of $f_n$ all lie in the $\varepsilon$-tube around the graph of $f$ if $n \ge N$. So for $n\ge N$, you should try to prove that $\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)| \le \varepsilon + M$, which I claim is visually clear from the picture of the $\varepsilon$-tube I described. This gives a uniform bound of $\varepsilon+M$ for $\{f_n:n\ge N\}$.

That leaves you to find a number that works to bound $f_1,\dots,f_{N-1}$ and $\{f_n:n\ge N\}$ all simultaneously. As a warm-up, what if $N = 2$? $N=3$?, do you see how to find such a number for general $N$ now?